# Trying to sort alphabetical/numerical array input without using predefined sort function C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to set up an ordered list for a college project that sorts movie titles into order as you add them to the array alphabetically and numerically. I have tried using an ordered list using numbers that I have working but, the add function does not order them when using strings.

Can anyone help me with the Add function? I need it to add the third entry I put into the array as the first as thats how it should be in a sorted list.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class OList
{
private:
    string data[3];
    int count; //First empty slot
public:
    OList();
    bool isEmpty();
    bool isFull();
    void Add(string newVal);
    string Remove(string newVal);
    bool LinearSearch(string searchVal);
    void Display();
};

OList::OList()
{
    count = 0;
}

bool OList::isEmpty()
{
    if (count == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool OList::isFull()
{
    if (count == 3)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

void OList::Add(string movie)
{
    data[count] = movie;
    int i ;
    if (isFull())
        return;

    //Find the insertion point
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++);

    if (i == count)
        data[i] = movie; //Copy in the new value
    else

        //Make a Space
        for (int j = count - 1; j >= i; j--)
        {
            data[j + 1] = data[j];
        }
    data[i] = movie; //Copy in the new value

    count++;
}

string OList::Remove(string movie)
{
    int i = LinearSearch(movie);
    string temp = movie;

    if (isEmpty())
        return false;
    i++;

    while (i < count - 1)
    {
        data[i] = data[i + 1];
        i++;
    }

    count--;
    return temp;
}

bool OList::LinearSearch(string searchVal)
{
    for (int i = 0; (i < count) || (data[i] > searchVal); i++)
    {
        if (data[i] == searchVal)
            return -1;
    }
    return false;
}

void OList::Display()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        cout << data[i] << endl;
    }
}



int main()
{
    OList movies;
    string movie;



    movies.Add("Yeh Jawaani Hai Deewani | 1, 790, 000, 000 | Ayan Mukerji");
    movies.Add("Dhoom 3 | 2,840,000,000 | Vijay Krishna Acharya");
    movies.Add("Chennai Express | 2, 275, 000, 000 | Rohit Shetty");

    movies.Display();

    std::cout << endl;

    movies.Remove("Chennai Express | 2, 275, 000, 000 | Rohit Shetty");



    if (!movies.isEmpty())
    {
        std::cout << "The queue is not empty!" << endl;
    }

    std::cout << endl;

    movies.Display();

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The answer to "Can anyone help me" is always yes. What kind of help do you need? What's the problem? What should your code be doing and what's it actually doing? Please make your question more specific.

Comment: There are many basic mistakes in there `for (i = 0; i < count; i++);` (note the semicolon) or `Add(movie="Yeh Jawaa")` (C++ is not python)

Comment: Where is the code that can sort numbers? It is easier to adapt that to strings, than to reinvent the sorting algorithm. (And if you don't actually have working code that sorts numbers, that is a good first step.)

Comment: Another mistake: arrays in C++ have indices starting at 0, so `data[3]` has indices 0, 1 and 2.  Your `Add` function quite happily writes to `data[3]` before checking if the `data` array is full.  This has undefined behaviour: your program may do the wrong thing, crash, do nothing, ostensibly do the right thing etc..

Comment: As for your main question: in `//Find the insertion point
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++);` change the condition to `i < count && data[i] > movie`.  Also try adding `std::cout << "x is " << x << '\n';`-style debugging statements to your code so you can see what values it's got at different times: that will help you understand what the code actually does and where it goes wrong.  Alternatively, use an interactive debugger.  Either approach will save you a lot of grief while learning to program.